# Print SQL statements of script run on Oracle DB with sqlplus

Tags: oracle, debugging, input, sqlplus

I'm using sqlplus to run a complex sql script and I'd like to be able to see the actual sql statement being run at the time along with the rest of the output. I've tried setting options such as 'set serveroutput' but I can't find the option that causes the sql being run to be written to stdout with the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> set echo on
SQL> @C:\AKS\aks_scripts\test.sql
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> select count(*) from user_objects;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       110

SQL>
SQL> select count(*) from emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        14

SQL>
SQL> select count(*) from testemp2;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    851968
```